# Silverstripe: I can't handle sub-URLs of a Form object. Subsites module

Tags: php, silverstripe

Bit of a long shot but can anyone shed any light on this?

I have recently installed the subsites module to run multiple sites from a single installation and am now getting the error: "I can't handle sub-URLs of a Form object." when I try to add descriptions/titles to image gallery objects. I have removed the subsites to verify that it is this which is causing the issue. I am using 2.4

I can upload images fine, however it is when trying to save a description from the popup that the issue arises.

I have tried with the default fields too and this still gives the same error.

My code:

```
<?php

class Gallery extends Page {

   public static $db = array( 
      'SummaryText'=>'Text', 
      'GalleryText'=>'Text' 
   ); 

   static $has_many = array( 
      'Photos' => 'GalleryPhoto' 
   ); 

   function getCMSFields() { 
      $fields = parent::getCMSFields(); 


      $manager = new ImageDataObjectManager( 
         $this, // Controller 
         'Photos', // Source name 
         'GalleryPhoto', // Source class 
         'Image' // File name on DataObject 
      ); 
      $manager->uploadFolder = $this->URLSegment; 


      $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Content.Main', new TextField('SummaryText', 'Summary Text (Appears in the section preview)'), 'Content'); 
      $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Content.Main', new TextField('GalleryText', 'Gallery Text (entering anything in here will overwrite any image Titles and Descriptions)'), 'Content'); 
      $fields->addFieldsToTab("Root.Content.Gallery", array($manager));             
      $fields->removeFieldFromTab('Root.Content', 'StyledText'); 
      $fields->removeFieldFromTab('Root.Content', 'Column2'); 
      $fields->removeFieldFromTab('Root.Content', 'Content'); 


      return $fields; 

   } 


}
```

..

```
<?php

class GalleryPhoto extends Photo {

   public static $db = array( 
      'HTMLDescription'=>'HTMLText' 
   ); 

   static $has_one = array( 
      'Gallery' => 'Gallery' 
   ); 

   public function getCMSFields(){ 
      $fields = parent::getCMSFields(); 
      $fields->removebyname('Description'); 
      $fields->removebyname('Title'); 
      $fields->replaceField('HTMLDescription', new SimpleTinyMCEField('HTMLDescription')); 
      return $fields; 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately "I can't handle sub-URLs of a Form object." is a pretty generic error message and from my experience rather tricky to debug.

To be honest, the Subsites module isn't that great in my opinion, it works, but its not that nice and not really compatible with other modules I guess.

I could imagine that the reason for your error is because silverstripe forgets the SubsiteID inside the popup and because of that SilverStripe can no longer find the current Page you are editing (because it adds a filter WHERE SubsiteID = x to every query of Pages you make)

one place to start debuging would be hooking into Subsite::currentSubsiteID() and see if it remembers the SubsiteID when you are in the popup

also, what is the exact url that gets called when you get the error message?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same error, searched for hours.  It was a problem with /framework/control/Session.php